# Shortest and longest paths between polygons

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, polygons

first of all I have to say, I am not a mathematician, I am software developer. Right now I am working on the app for pilots.

Part of the app is creation of the navigation task. The task is defined by turn points in certain order which could be lines, circles, but let's say just general polygons.

I want to find algorithm for computing longest and shortest paths between all the polygons. I have to keep the order of the polygons and it doesn't matter if I just touch the border of the polygon or go right through the center. I just have to visit all of them.

I expect to find two sets of points. One set defining the shortest path and one set for the longest one. Each point lies within corresponding turn point polygon.

Could you please help me find a solution? Thank you.

[image: Example]

Comment: Could you give examples? Especially for longest paths.

Comment: Are your turn point regions convex and disjoint? If so, a very simple "hill-climbing" algorithm will work fine. I.e. pick any valid set of points for the path, and repeatedly check each point in the path one by one to see if it can be moved within its turn point region (without moving any other points) such that the path is made shorter/longer. When none of the points can be moved any further, you're done.

Comment: No, my regions could be both convex/concave and don't have to be disjoint. Would this algorithm still works?

Comment: @lhf sure, see example in my edited question.